# How to create the highest quality Android buttons?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, photoshop

I have been designing/creating buttons for my apps, but when I compare to them to highly successful commercial apps like Google+ or Facebook, the image quality just does not look the same. I have viewed the buttons on the emulator and on devices.

I use Photoshop CS5 and always make sure I am designing the .png in RGB and 300 DPI.
[image]

I then create the button in XML specifying the pressed and focused states:

**about_btn.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/about_down"
          android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/about_down"
          android:state_focused="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/about_up" />
</selector>
```

I then use the button in my layout like so:

**main.xml**

```
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/about_button_xml"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/about_btn"
            android:paddingTop="5dp" />
```

Is there some type of flaw in the way the buttons are being scaled in the layout or am i saving/designing the buttons a bad format, am I using the wrong software....i am just not sure.

What do design specifications and software do you recommend? Any suggestions or tutorials would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: checkout this link
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add a little specificity to m0skit0's answer: You should probably be designing at 320dpi. Take the 320dpi version and put it in `drawable-xhdpi`, and put 240 and 160 dpi scaled versions in `drawable-hdpi` and `drawable-mdpi`. If you don't provide a resource at the density of the device's screen, the system *will* attempt to scale up a lower-density image (or scale down a higher-density one if one is provided, but it rarely does it as well as Photoshop and can't use judgment about how to scale odd-sized parts of the image crisply when necessary).

If you only provide an image in the `drawable` folder, the system will assume it's 160dpi for historical reasons - and that's almost certainly not what you want; you'll end up with a fuzzy, overly large, and upscaled version of your original image.

Concretely: a 100px image in `drawable-mdpi` or just plain `drawable` will be rendered as a 200px image on an xhdpi screen using scaling. If you really designed that image at ~320dpi to be 100px, the right thing is to put the 100px version in `drawable-xhdpi`, a 50px version in `drawable-mdpi`, and a 75px version in `drawable-hdpi`.

Google writes a lot about this on their site; see their [designer info](http://developer.android.com/design/style/devices-displays.html) and [dev info](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#screen-independence). Visually:

[image: Scaled icons]
([CC Attribution 2.5](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/2.5/) licensed image from the above Android Designer site).

Comment: thank you, this along with reading the links answered my question. I was designing at the wrong DPI as well as not designing for the other formats. How do these formats effect my layouts in layout-land and layout-large? What is the difference between layout-large and layout-xhdpi? seems confusing to use them both....

Answer (score 3):

Some devices have no way to display 300 dpis, so your image has to be scaled. This is a hardware limitation.

This is why you have the `res/drawable-xdpi`, `res/drawable-hdpi`... folders, to provide an image for each different DPI density.

More info about this topic [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design.html#icon-sets).